# DependencyException: Failed to find provider with satisfied dependency set for interface org.ehcache.core.spi.store.Store

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I have an app that uses EHCache, it worked when using *Payara Application server* version `1.0.5` but after upgrading to `1.1.0` it started breaking.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
persistentEntityStoreCacheManager 
    = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder().withCache("defaultPersistentEntityStoreCache",
                      CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, PersistentEntityStore.class, ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(100)).build()).build(true);
```

And it is throwing this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.ehcache.core.spi.ServiceLocator$DependencyException: Failed to find provider with satisfied dependency set for interface org.ehcache.core.spi.store.Store$Provider [ca
ndidates []]
        at org.ehcache.core.spi.ServiceLocator$DependencySet.build(ServiceLocator.java:350)
        at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.resolveServices(EhcacheManager.java:154)
        at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.<init>(EhcacheManager.java:125)
        at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.<init>(EhcacheManager.java:115)
        at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.<init>(EhcacheManager.java:111)
        at org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManager(CacheManagerBuilder.java:117)
        at org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder.build(CacheManagerBuilder.java:73)
```

What's this EHCache and and what could be missing here?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest EhCache jar files in your project

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there are multiple EhCache imported by different modules.After useing the same version of EhCache. The problem solved.